# Unity - How To Make a 2d grid movement system

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

So, I am trying to make a game that requires the user to move up or down on a vertical axis, it needs to be precise however so I want the character to move on a grid, how would this be possible? if anyone could help it would be well appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: The question's too broad and there are probably hundreds of ways to go around it. I'd suggest taking a stab at it in whatever way occurs to you and when you hit a specific issue make (or search for) a question around that issue.

Comment: Alright I will take a deeper look through google, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

@voldemort is right, but I can try to recommend a strategy.
Think of checking for each frame, then in the Update () function, if you have pressed a stast, then:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode._upKey)
        transform.Translate (Vector2.up * _size_of_the_grid_box);
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode._downKey)
        transform.Translate(Vector2.down * _size_of_the_grid_box);
}
```

This code simply moves the gameObject up a certain value when a button is pressed, and down when another button is pressed.